# Calculate QGraphicsTextItem font size based on scale

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I have `QGraphicsTextItem` objects on a `QGraphicsScene`. The user can scale the `QGraphicsTextItem` objects by dragging the corners. (I am using a custom "transformation editor" to do this.) The user can also change the size of the `QGraphicsTextItem` by changing the font size from a property panel. What I would like to do is unify these so that when the user scales the object by dragging the corner with the mouse, behind the scenes it actually is calculating "What size font is necessary to make the resulting object fit the target size and keep the scale factor at 1.0?"

What I am doing now is letting the object scale as normal using `QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent` and then triggering a `FinalizeMapScale` method in `QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent` once the mouse scale is complete. This method should then change the font to the appropriate size and set the scale back to 1.0.

I have a solution that appears to be working, but I'm not crazy about it. I'm relatively new to both Qt and C++, so would appreciate any comments or corrections.

- Is there a better way to architect this whole thing?
- Are there Qt methods that already do this?
- Is my method on the right track but has some Qt or C++ errors?

Feel free to comment on my answer below on submit your own preferred solution. Thanks!

**[EDIT]** As requested in comment, here is the basics of the scaling code. We actually went a different direction with this, so this code (and the code below) is no longer being used. This code is in the `mouseMoveEvent` method, having previously set a "scaling_" flag to true in `mousePressEvent` if the mouse was clicked in the bottom-right "hot spot". Note that this code is in a decorator QGraphicsItem that holds a pointer to the target it is scaling. This abstraction was necessary for our project, but is probably overkill for most uses.

```
void TransformDecorator::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
  ...
  if (scaling_) {
    QGraphicsItem *target_item = target_->AsQGraphicsItem();
    target_item->setTransformOriginPoint(0.0, 0.0);
    QPointF origin_scene = mapToScene(target_item->transformOriginPoint());
    QPointF scale_position_scene = mapToScene(event->pos());
    qreal unscaled_width = target_item->boundingRect().width();
    qreal scale_x = (scale_position_scene.x() - origin_scene.x()) / unscaled_width;
    if (scale_x * unscaled_width < kMinimumSize) {
      scale_x = kMinimumSize / unscaled_width;
    }
    target_item->setScale(scale_x);
  } else {
    QGraphicsObject::mouseMoveEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please no holy wars about the loop-with-exit construct. We're comfortable with it.*

```
void MapTextElement::FinalizeMapScale() {

  // scene_document_width is the width of the text document as it appears in
  // the scene after scaling. After we are finished with this method, we want
  // the document to be as close as possible to this width with a scale of 1.0.
  qreal scene_document_width = document()->size().width() * scale();

  QString text = toPlainText();

  // Once the difference between scene_document_width and the calculated width
  // is below this value, we accept the new font size.
  const qreal acceptable_delta = 1.0;

  // If the difference between scene_document_width and the calculated width is
  // more than this value, we guess at the new font size by calculating a new
  // scale factor. Once it is beneath this value, we creep up (or down) by tiny
  // increments. Without this, we would sometimes incur long "back and forth"
  // loops when using the scale factor.
  const qreal creep_delta = 8.0;
  const qreal creep_increment = 0.1;

  QScopedPointer<QTextDocument> test_document(document()->clone());
  QFont new_font = this->font();
  qreal delta = 0.0;

  // To prevent infinite loops, we store the font size values that we try.
  // Because of the unpredictable (at least to me) relationship between font
  // point size and rendering size, this was the only way I could get it to
  // work reliably.
  QList<qreal> attempted_font_sizes;

  while (true) {

    test_document->setDefaultFont(new_font);
    delta = scene_document_width - test_document->size().width();

    if (std::abs(delta) <= acceptable_delta ||
        attempted_font_sizes.contains(new_font.pointSizeF())) {
      break;
    }

    attempted_font_sizes.append(new_font.pointSizeF());

    qreal new_font_size = 0.0;
    if (std::abs(delta) <= creep_delta) {
      new_font_size = delta > 0.0 ? new_font.pointSizeF() + creep_increment
                                  : new_font.pointSizeF() - creep_increment;
    } else {
      new_font_size = new_font.pointSizeF()
                      * scene_document_width
                      / test_document->size().width();
    }
    new_font.setPointSizeF(new_font_size);
  }

  this->setFont(new_font);
  this->setScale(1.0);
}
```

Comment: I think you might be better off with a bisecting algorithm, one that has as a lower bound your current font size and as an upper bound something reasonable. Then you should have an O(log N) solution for some N dependent on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem is: Qt has scaled the font, what is the effective font size (as it appears to the user, not the font size set in the text item) that I need to display to the user as their choice of new font size?  This is just an alternative, you still need a calculation similar to yours.

I have a similar problem.  I have a text item that I want to be unit size (one pixel size) like my other unit graphic items (and then the user can scale them.)  What  font (setPointSize) needs to be set?  (Also what setTextWidth and what setDocumentMargin?) The advantage of this design is that you don't need to treat the scaling of text items different than the scaling of any other shape of graphics item. (But I don't have it working yet.)

Also, a user interface issue: if the user changes the font size, does the item change size? Or does it stay the same size and the text wrap differently, leaving more or less blank space at the end of the text?  When the user appends new text, does the font size change so all the text fits in the size of the shape, or does the shape size grow to accommodate more text? In other words, is it more like a flowchart app (where the shape size is fixed and the font shrinks), or like a word processor app (where the font size is constant and the shape (number of pages) grows?